# Are you giving me the silent treatment because of a question I asked?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that after I asked a question that got downvotes and then I subsequently deleted, I stopped getting replies to my chatroom.

My job was about what jobs gentile Germans had, because even in a site about the Holocaust, it still says things like "62 percent of all lawyers in Vienna were Jewish." It can't be that Jewish people held the majority to *all* jobs, because that would be impossible.

http://www.holocaustresearchproject.org/nazioccupation/anschluss.html
"The Jewish population in Vienna declined dramatically during the years of the Austrian Republic (1918 -1938), yet their profile amongst the population in certain areas of the city increased. Mainly due to industrial, professional and economic factors. According to Jewish scholars at the time, 62 percent of all lawyers in Vienna were Jewish. 47 percent of physicians, and nearly 29 percent of all University professors were also Jewish."

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak for anyone else, but this wasn't the only chat having this issue. I got super busy at work this week, and while I was still doing my normal mod stuff, when I logged back on on my Friday off, I noticed that **both our Time Machine chat and our HNQ chat had been locked for inactivity**. I had to manually reactivate both of them.

Yeah, a lot of that is on me. Perhaps most of it. However, it also means nobody else was using or watching over them.

I'm not really sure why, but this apparently was just not a chatty week for people.

Comment: OK, I understand. Sorry about that.